# Como castear un String a varios enteros separados Java

Tags: java

Tengo una entrada por consola que tiene dos datos enteros separados pero en una sola línea, es decir, si el input es "2 4" tengo que almacenar en una variable el 2 y en otra el 4. (Estas como tipo int).
Para esto debo usar la libreria BufferedReader, intenté esto pero no me compila.

```
int n,m;
n = Integer.parseInt(sc.readLine());
m = Integer.parseInt(sc.readLine());
```

Gracias.

Comment: Lo que tienes que hacer es pedir una sola vez el valor (en el ejemplo lo pides 2 veces), después con la función split de la clase string (usando el espacio como separador) y una vez que lo tienes ya por partes, con Integer.parseInt lo pasas a unas variables enteras

Answer (score 1):

Hola puedes utilizar el método `split` la cual realiza la división de una cadena mediante un parámetro en este caso seria el espacio.
Te dejare un ejemplo espero puedas adaptarlo a tu programa:

```
String entrada = "2 4";
String[] numeros = entrada.split(" ");
int numero1 = Integer.parseInt(numeros[0]);
int numero2 = Integer.parseInt(numeros[1]);
```

Saludos y mucha suerte.

Comment: @deminrc para evitar confuisiones podrías modificar tu respuesta por favor y poner **método** split, en lugar de **clase**